# High charts update data series

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to update the data series with Series.update() So, if you click on the Allocation Funds, the lines should change. However, only the first set of data are being updated, the rest are not. Can you help me with why and how can I fix it? Thank you! http://jsfiddle.net/5cur7gg4/1/

```
chart2.series[0].update({
    data:[-3.49 , 9.21 , 9.21 , 4.36 , 17.74 , null],
    color: '#588c7e',
    name:"A"
},{
    data:[-1.47 , 6.89 , 6.89 , 7.06  , 12.95 , 12.45],
    color: '#f2e394',
    name:"B"
},{
    data:[-2.57 , 7.46, 7.46, 3.00, 19.45, null],
    color: '#f2ae72',
    name:"C"
},{
    data:[-2.42 , 8.46, 8.46, 16.50, 21.27, null],
    color: '#d96459',
    name:"D"
},
{
    data:[-1.23, 6.31, 6.31, 5.49, 15.48, 14.81],
    color: '#8c4646',
    name:"E"
});
```

Comment: looks like you updating the same series 0, however there are 5 so you need to push data to each set.  http://jsfiddle.net/9k85rx0r/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update individual series like this.

```
chart2.series[0].update({
        data:[-3.49 , 9.21 , 9.21 , 4.36 , 17.74 , null],
        color: '#588c7e',
        name:"A"
    },false);
    chart2.series[1].update({
        data:[-1.47 , 6.89 , 6.89 , 7.06  , 12.95 , 12.45],
        color: '#f2e394',
        name:"B"
    }, false);
    chart2.series[2].update({
        data:[-2.57 , 7.46, 7.46, 3.00, 19.45, null],
        color: '#f2ae72',
        name:"C"
    }, false);
    chart2.series[3].update({
        data:[-3.42 , 8.46, 8.46, 16.50, 21.27, null],
        color: '#d96459',
        name:"D"
    }, false);
    chart2.series[4].update({
        data:[-4.23, 6.31, 6.31, 5.49, 15.48, 14.81],
        color: '#8c4646',
        name:"E"
    }, true);
```

Comment: You should set false flag in all update instead of last. Then you avoid 5 redraw, only one.

Comment: @SebastianBochan thanks, done. I thought default value of that flag is false.